# How to create a cluster of pins with OpenLayers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have read some example but i don't still don't know how to cluster the pins using OpenLayers.Strategy.Cluster. I saw some of the examples using OpenLayers.Layer.Vector() but i do not know how to implement it correctly. Plus how do i define the feature, its attributes and add it to the cluster?

Comment: See gmaps4rails codebase, I've done it there: https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.openlayers.js.coffee#L121

Comment: hi, i had did it previously in using map, but now i am changing it to openstreetmap. I am finding a way to do so.